# Does she have or has she got? Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, questions

I'm not sure which one is correct. I had read that "does have" is more likely used in American English and "has got" in British English. But which one of these is correct?

> What kind of hobbies does Jessica have?
>
> What kind of hobbies has Jessica got?

Comment: The first example is good, but you don't "get" hobbies. The second usage could be better as, say,  "Has Jessica got style?".

Comment: @WeatherVane One can "get oneself a hobby".

Comment: Does Jessica have any hobbies?

Answer (score 1):

Both the usages are correct but

> what kind of hobbies does she have

is more in use.

> What kind of hobbies has she?
>
> What kind of hobbies has she (got)?

is mainly considered to be BrE.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=YK0vJYdxMNQC&pg=PA122&dq=%22got+a+hobby%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJx_PMgbjZAhWGEiwKHRluDksQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q=%22got%20a%20hobby%22&f=false) is "Have you got a hobby?" in a book by a British guy (I think Scottish).

[Here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=EZEtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&dq=%22hobbies+does+she+have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid4_6GgrjZAhVGiSwKHSO5BTIQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=%22hobbies%20does%20she%20have%22&f=false) is "What hobbies does she have?" in a book by a British writer [Louise Beech](https://louisebeech.co.uk/the-books/).

[Here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=aNENAQAAMAAJ&q=%22hobbies+has+he+got%22&dq=%22hobbies+has+he+got%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilvbL8hLjZAhUCXiwKHT_sBtMQ6AEIKDAA) is "What hobbies has he got?" in a book by an American journalist (from 1969).

However, your question with "has Jessica got" does sound a bit unnatural, and I'm just going to throw out some guesses as to why that might be.

The thing is, "'s got" as a synonym for "have" has become something of an ungrammatical idiom, to the point that it's now OK to ask, *"What do you got here?"* (meaning "What do you have here?")—although it is, of course, very much a colloquial expression.

Twisting and turning it back and forth into different positions in the sentence trying to adhere to the rules of grammar does seem to blur the lines between "get" as in "obtain something" and "have got" as a synonym "have".

Leave "have got" to simple sentences like "I've got/She's got" or a simple question "Have you got?" and don't shun sentences with "does she have."

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but, for whatever reason, the "does he have" form is considered more "elegant" than the "has he got" form.  It's less a question of which is "correct" and which fits how you choose to speak.

> What kind of dog **does he have**? (more formal/polite)
>
> What kind of dog **has he got**? (less formal/polite)

These days, of course, there is a dismal lack of eloquence even at the highest levels of government, so we all may have to reevaluate our standards.

Comment: I wouldn't characterize "has got" as *crude*, necessarily. It's certainly more informal, but calling it crude carries more heavily negative connotations than I think it warrants. It's definitely not crude to the same extent as, say, using profanity would be considered crude.

Comment: @Sparksbet  As I said, standards have changed.  It used to be we expected our national leaders to speak in complete sentences with words of more than one syllable, for example.  Nowadays, profanity is so ubiquitous as to retain very little *crudity*.  In any case, I've edited my answer to say that one is more *elegant* than the other.

Comment: "Elegant" is no less judgmental. One is slightly more formal than the other - why can't you leave it at that factual assertion rather than insisting that "have got" is less elegant and indicdtes less eloquence on the part of the speaker.

Comment: @Sparksbet  I didn't create the judgement of one over the other, I merely report on it.  But if you really believe that these both sound equal to any native speaker, then we must agree to disagree.

Comment: I did not say they were equal - "do have" is more formal than "have got". That is the difference between them. "Elegance" and "crudity" are value judgments you're placing (without justification, imo) on the use of these phrases, implying that using the more informal variant is a question of how eloquent a speaker is rather than of how formally they chose to speak in a particular context.

Answer (score 0):

In everyday speech you will hear both used interchangeably, and most people will not pick up on the difference, although technically there *is* a difference.

Both phrases are grammatically correct as shown. The difference is in the verbs *have* and *got*.

- **Have** means to possess, and is in the *present tense*.
- **Got** is the *past* participle of the verb *to get*.

Technically speaking, the first phrase is the correct one:

> What kind of hobbies does Jessica **have**?

This is because you are asking about the *present tense* - what kind of hobbies Jessica *currently* has.

The second example is phrased correctly...

> What kind of hobbies **has** Jessica **got**?

.. because the verb *has* puts it into the present tense. But saying "*has got"* technically refers to the *past act of getting* something rather than *possessing something in the present*.