# Meaning of "grow into"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Could you explain what the phrase actually means?

> 56' | Jez really **growing into** this game now.
>
> The young winger is really trying to play when he's got the ball at
> his feet, driving forward and taking on his man, whilst most
> importantly doing the simple things right.

1-2

#Spireites | #ALTCFC

Comment: Please give the source of your examples, with a link if possible.

Comment: This seems to be a basic question about the meaning of a verb ("to have got"). Did you do any research on that verb?

Comment: There are several duplicates on the use of "has got" to mean "has". There is no special football use here, " he's got the ball" means exactly the same as "he has the ball".

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157321/does-she-have-or-has-she-got-which-one-is-correct explains the second question, so I've removed it from this post

Answer (score 1):

"grow into" is a little idiom.  If a child had some clothes that were too big, but the child grows and the clothes fit him, you say, "The child has grown into the clothes".

> Jays school uniform was baggy in September, but now it's Christmas and he's growing into it.  It will be too tight by Summer!

Metaphorically, at the start of the match, Jez was not playing at the same level as the other players.  But he has developed and improved during the match, and he is now playing as skillfully as the other players.